# Rgb sequence garbage printed when I open terminal in vim

Tags: vim, tmux, alacritty

I use tmux, alacrity and vim on OSX Catalina.
Each time I open a terminal inside of vim, the terminal opens with this gibberish being printed:

```
4;0;rgb:28/28/284;1;rgb:fb/49/344;2;rgb:b8/bb/264;3;rgb:fa/bd/2f4;4;rgb:83/a5/984;5;rgb:d3/86/9b4;6;rgb:8e/c0/7c4;7;rgb:
d5/c4/a14;8;rgb:66/5c/544;9;rgb:fb/49/344;10;rgb:b8/bb/264;11;rgb:fa/bd/2f4;12;rgb:83/a5/984;13;rgb:d3/86/9b4;14;rgb:8e/
c0/7c4;15;rgb:fb/f1/c74;16;rgb:fe/80/194;17;rgb:d6/5d/0e4;18;rgb:3c/38/364;19;rgb:50/49/454;20;rgb:bd/ae/934;21;rgb:eb/d
b/b210;rgb:d5/c4/a111;rgb:28/28/2812;7%
```

It forces me to type `clear` each time I want to use the terminal inside vim, and that's annoying.

I have this in my `tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"
```

and this in my `vimrc` file:

```
if !has('gui_running') && &term =~ '^\%(screen\|tmux\)'
   let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
   let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
endif

colorscheme darcula
```

and this in my `alacrity.yml`:

```
shell:
  program: /bin/zsh
  args:
    - -l
    - -c
    - "tmux attach || tmux"
env:
  TERM: xterm-256color
```

The output of `vim --version` is:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Sep 01 2022 15:00:53)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-350
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        +lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework AppKit -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.4 -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/perl/lib/perl5/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc -L/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-darwin -lpython3.10 -framework CoreFoundation -lruby.3.1 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2_1/lib
```

I've looked into number of solutions that I've found but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: How about listing the number of solutions you have looked into so that we don't waste your and our time suggesting them again? FWIW, tmux always makes things more complicated with Vim and Alacritty is buggy as hell if you don't use its official termcap.

Comment: Alacrity is not buggy for me at all except this problem